# Not all arguments converted during string formatting (Flask, ImageMagick and SQLAlchemy_ImageAttach)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, imagemagick, wand

I can't really make any sense of this error. When I try to commit a change to user.picture, it sends the error written in the title. I haven't been able to find any other example of this error occurring in anything related to this.

Here's the error:

```
not all arguments converted during string formatting on line 429
```

Line 429 reads like so:

```
db.session.commit()
```

Here's my store:

```
store = FileSystemStore(
    path='bin/static/img',
    base_url='/'
)
```

If I use a store like this instead, I get the same error:

```
store = HttpExposedFileSystemStore(
    path='bin/static/img/',
    prefix='static/img/'
)
```

Here's an example of me attempting to commit a given picture

```
with store_context(main.AppClass.store):
    current_user.picture.from_file(_profile_picture)
    db.session.commit()
```

Here's an example of me trying to do the same with binary instead

```
with store_context(main.AppClass.store):
    byte_str = base64.b64encode(_profile_picture.read())
    decoded_byte_str = base64.b64decode(byte_str)
    current_user.picture.from_blob(decoded_byte_str)
    db.session.commit()
```

They both give me the same error, which leads me to believe there may be something wrong with my Store, but I can't really begin to comprehend how.

However, if I do something like this instead as a test to see if it works at all:

```
  with store_context(main.AppClass.store):
      current_user.set_name("asd")
      db.session.commit()
```

It commits with no issue. I'm sort of at a loss here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the error message suggest a filename? You might be looking at the wrong file.

Comment: Please include the full traceback.